# Pandas DateTime only partially showing in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, python-datetime

**Problem:** I am trying to make a bar chart based on a very simple Pandas DataFrame that has a DateTime index and integers in one column. Data below. Only some of the data is showing up in Matplotlib, however.

**Code:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,6))
ax.bar(unique_opps_by_month.index, unique_opps_by_month['Opportunity Name'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((1,4,7,10)))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b'))
ax.set_xlim('2016-01', '2021-04')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

The output, however, looks like:
[image]

This doesn't match the data though! There should be eight bars in 2017, and not all the same height. There are similar problems in the other years as well. **Why are only some of the bars showing? How can I make Matplotlib show all the data?**

**Data**

```
2016-02-01  1
2016-05-01  1
2016-08-01  1
2016-09-01  1
2017-01-01  1
2017-02-01  1
2017-03-01  1
2017-04-01  1
2017-07-01  3
2017-10-01  2
2017-11-01  3
2017-12-01  1
2018-02-01  2
2018-03-01  2
2018-04-01  2
2018-06-01  1
2018-07-01  1
2018-08-01  1
2018-11-01  1
2018-12-01  2
2019-03-01  5
2019-04-01  2
2019-05-01  1
2019-06-01  2
2019-07-01  1
2019-08-01  2
2019-09-01  4
2019-11-01  5
2020-01-01  4
2020-02-01  6
2020-03-01  1
2020-06-01  1
2020-07-01  2
2020-09-01  3
2020-10-01  5
2020-11-01  4
2020-12-01  6
2021-01-01  3
2021-02-01  6
2021-03-01  3
```

Comment: Try increasing the `width` parameter of `Axes.bar`.

Comment: This worked. I added "width=18" right in the ax.bar() call, and now I can see everything. Why does this work though? Why are some bars visible but some not unless I specify a larger width?

Comment: Because the default width is 0.8 IIRC and just too small for all bars to be plotted visibly.

Comment: Got it, thank you!